# Cmake on Linux Lite 3.6

Tags: apt, compiling, cmake

I am trying to build "Transmission" on my machine with Linux Lite v3.6, but cmake is needed. Successfully installed it with `sudo apt install cmake`, but it installed only cmake 3.5.1. And transmission needs at least 3.9. How to install 3.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux lite is just an adoption of the Ubuntu long-time stable releases.

The oldest still supported of these is Ubuntu 18.04, which already shipped with cmake 3.10. I think Linux lite v3 is based on the now-defunct Ubuntu 16.04.

So, your Linux lite must be very very ancient, and you will very likely encounter much more missing components even if you managed to Backport cmake to it.

It is time to update your Linux distribution. (That is definitely the easiest and least work way of getting cmake >= 3.9, so this is the answer to your literal question.)

Your Linux platform is long out of service. Also, honestly, if you know how to download the source code of transmission and try building it, you're already more proficient with Linux system administration that most of Ubuntu users are. So not sure how much you benefit from Linux lite's restrictions:)

Maybe going for a mainstream Linux distro like xubuntu, which is just like Linux lite, xfce running on the Ubuntu distribution base, just with a much richer selection of software and a much larger user base to draw from, makes your life easier. In your specific case, not going Linux lite but an official Ubuntu spin like xubuntu would have allowed you to directly install transmission via apt.

Comment: But im using Linux lite, because my laptop have only 2GB of RAM. Im tried other OS's, but the consume more RAM then this linux

Comment: Lite Linux really isn't very different than xubuntu. No matter what Linux distro you use, you will have to update it.

Comment: If i just do apt upgrade this will upgrade linux version?

Comment: No, it won't! If you scroll down in this page: https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/on-topic/can-i-upgrade-linux-lite-to-the-next-series/ you'll find instructions. Unlike "proper" Ubuntu, the upgrade process is manual as it seems. That's why I think it's a bad idea to use "fringe" Linux distros in such use cases as yours: things just aren't as smooth.

Comment: Ok, clean reinstall is not problem for me, because i installed Linux lite yesterday with dualboot with Windows

Comment: Hm, Xubuntu is heavier than Linux lite according to system requirements

Comment: But if you installed it yesterday, why did you install a version from six years ago?

Comment: Are you *sure* about the system requirements: https://xubuntu.org/requirements/ says something different (I'll be as bold as saying that 768 MB vs 1 GB of RAM make little difference, unless you're one of the few (and probably ill-advised, performance-wise) people that use an odd number of RAM modules, or use RAM modules of different sizes.) Also, really, Linux Lite is for most that it is just … Ubuntu. Ubuntu running XFCE. The same as xubuntu does; the software differences really are mostly in the "menus and control centers" GUIs.

Comment: Because it is latest x32 ver

Comment: hm, do you have a 32 bit computer? If that's the case, you'll have to switch to a distro that still offers support for that! Currently, you're not even getting security updates anymore, which is very dangerous.

Comment: You should try the [debian i386 live + nonfree](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/11.5.0-live+nonfree/i386/iso-hybrid/) installer. Scroll down to "debian-live-11.5.0-i386-xfce+nonfree.iso" and use that for installation. It has the same XFCE as Linux Lite and Xubuntu, just styled a bit differently than Linux Live. During Debian installation, you must make sure to select "Xfce desktop environment" at the "Selecting and Installing Software installation" step.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Now im using AntiX and i successfully  build transmission from source!

Comment: uff AntiX. You're really set on using niche Linux distros. AntiX is kind of an extreme Distro in the sense that all the other distros use a relatively user-friendly system management tool, and AntiX rejects that. Have fun, though! Also, on a modern AntiX there's no reason to build transmission from source. That should just be installable from repositories, if I'm not mistaken!

Comment: Yes, it already preinstalled there.